# Searching for array index in a multi dimentional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have an array like

```
Array ( 
     [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [SSN] => 123456789 [borrowerName] => Peter K  ) ) 
     [1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [SSN] => 412516789 [borrowerName] => Jack P  ) ) 
     [2] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [SSN] => 999338999 [borrowerName] => Angel M  ) ) 
)
```

I want to be able to search for an SSN and get back the index of where it is

for example `search($array,'SSN','412516789')` should return 1

Comment: What is the point of the multidimensional array here? Your data could easily be expressed w/o the second array.

Comment: Just `foreach()` the parent array and rummage around for what you want. php's array search functions aren't built for multidimensional searching.

Comment: Changing the structure is not exactly an option so I will have to work with this. foreach would be very inefficient

Answer (score 2):

Of course you need a foreach. Can't do otherwise.

```
function search($array,$key,$value) {
  foreach($array as $k=>$v) {
    if ($v[0][$key]==$value)
      return $k;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some function searching recursively in a multidim array, you may want to adapt it to your needs.

```
function findInMultiDim($array, $value){
    if(in_array($value,$array)) return TRUE;
    foreach($array as $v){
        if(is_array($v)){
            $result = findInMultiDim($v, $value);
            if($result === TRUE){
                return TRUE;
            }
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```